# Minecraft 1.8 crashes on Ubuntu MATE 19.10

Tags: java, launcher, minecraft

I have java 8 and openjdk 8 installed and have the launcher set to them, but I get an error still.

Output on launcher: Unable to locate the java runtime
                    Error details: Success
                    Filename on disk: java
                    Path: usr/bin/java
                    Exists: Nonexistent

Nothing shows in the logs. Just the first few lines it normally starts with (preparing launch, checking installation, etc.

Would really love a fix cause I played this all the time on windows, but finally could get ahold of a laptop that was actually mine, so I could use linux and I really want to play it on my own computer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, try sudo apt install minecraft-launcher .

Comment: "*Unable to locate the java runtime*" seems to be the problem. Show us the complete output (in your question above) of `ls -la /usr/bin/java`. Be sure to format the output correctly so it's readable.